# Are Apache Spark 2.0 parquet files incompatible with Apache Arrow?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, parquet, databricks, pyarrow

## The problem

I have written an Apache Spark DataFrame as a parquet file for a deep learning application in a Python environment ; I am currently experiencing issues in implementing basic examples of both petastorm (following [this notebook](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/_static/notebooks/deep-learning/petastorm.html)) and [horovod](https://horovod.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spark_include.html) frameworks, in reading the aforementioned file namely. The DataFrame has the following type : `DataFrame[features: array<float>, next: int, weight: int]` (much like in DataBricks' notebook, I had `features` be a VectorUDT, which I converted to an array).
In both cases, Apache Arrow throws an `ArrowIOError : Invalid parquet file. Corrupt footer.` error.

## What I found until now

I discovered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41854135/enable-metadata-files-in-spark-2-1-0) and in [this PR](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/13455) that as of version 2.0, Spark doesn't write `_metadata` or `_common_metadata` files, unless `spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata` is set to `true` in Spark's configuration ; those files are indeed missing.
I thus tried rewriting my DataFrame with this environment, still no `_common_metadata` file. What also works is to explicitely pass a schema to petastorm when constructing a reader (passing `schema_fields` to `make_batch_reader` for instance ; which is a problem with horovod as there is no such parameter in `horovod.spark.keras.KerasEstimator`'s constructor).

How would I be able, if at all possible, to either make Spark output those files, or in Arrow to infer the schema, just like Spark seems to be doing ?

## Minimal example with horovod

```py
# Saving df
print(spark.config.get('spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata')) # outputs 'true'
df.repartition(10).write.mode('overwrite').parquet(path)

# ...

# Training
import horovod.spark.keras as hvd
from horovod.spark.common.store import Store

model = build_model()
opti = Adadelta(learning_rate=0.015)
loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
store = Store().create(prefix_path=prefix_path,
                       train_path=train_path,
                       val_path=val_path)
keras_estimator = hvd.KerasEstimator(
    num_proc=16,
    store=store,
    model=model,
    optimizer=opti,
    loss=loss,
    feature_cols=['features'],
    label_cols=['next'],
    batch_size=auto_steps_per_epoch,
    epochs=auto_nb_epochs,
    sample_weight_col='weight'
)

keras_model = keras_estimator.fit_on_parquet() # Fails here with ArrowIOError
```

Comment: This sounds like there is a file produced by Spark in the folder of files that is not actually a Parquet and should be ignored by Apache Arrow. Can you have a look into that folder and see if there one? At the moment, only the `_SUCCESS` file is ignored, all other files are expected to be Parquet files.

Comment: @UweL.Korn Indeed, I add the underscore files to the list of ignored files just like in the example notebook for petastorm.

Comment: @al.one what version of pyarrow are you using? The issue with underscores that is linked in the notebook (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-4723) should already have been solved in pyarrow 0.14

Comment: @joris I was using version 0.13 which was provided in my databricks runtime environment - I installed version 0.14 and it works like a charm. Thak you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved in pyarrow 0.14+ ([issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-4723](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-4723)), be sure to install the updated version with pip (up until Databricks Runtime 6.5, the included version is 0.13).
Thanks to [@joris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/653364/joris)' comment for pointing this out.